# Trigger (on mutating tables) updates older data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I tried to update one table from another by row trigger and there is a problem with it.

Trigger works after I add PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.. but works in a strange way.

Oracle version 12c.
I have a similar (simplified) code :

```
create table w_mutating2 (id number);

insert into  w_mutating1 values (NULL); commit;

create or replace trigger w_mutate_trg1
before insert on w_mutating2 
for each row
declare 
pragma autonomous_transaction;

begin 
    update w_mutating1 set num =  (select max(id) from w_mutating2); 
    commit;

end; 
/

insert into w_mutating2 values (2); 
commit;

select * from w_mutating1;
select * from w_mutating2;
```

After that my table w_mutating1 is with NULL value.
So I execute it once again

```
insert into w_mutating2 values (5); 
commit;

select * from w_mutating1;
select * from w_mutating2;
```

my table w_mutating have value => 2
So my trigger works.. but one operation too late ;)
In my complex example I use function in similar trigger.
When I execute function with parameters from command line it works. Data is ok.
But when I execute it from trigger (with PRAGMA autonomous_transaction) it update my data as above.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: I don't really understand here what is the problem, and what do you think is not working. do you expect oracle to update a null the first insert ? I ran the same as you and works as it should be.

Comment: `pragma autonomous_transaction` means execute in a separate transaction (as if it was done in another session), so it can't see the new value until it's committed. But why not populate `id` sequentially? Then you won't need to query the table to find the highest value.

Comment: DO not do that.  read up about compound triggers for handling mutating issues

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I expected that after I insert first value which is commited, trigger will find it as maximum element and it update my second table, but I still have "null". After I insert next row ( with id = 5 ) and commit it, my second table is updated with id = 1 , not id = 5 as I expected

Comment: It's likely that you don't need a trigger or a second table at all, just a sequence. Please edit your question with the problem you are trying to solve with this solution. @WilliamRobertson has already explained why this isn't going to give you anything useful.

Comment: @fazi_87, obviously you don't understand how transaction isolation works. when you issue `pragma_autonomous_transaction` a new transaction starts in another session, but the original one has not yet either commit or rollback, therefore the code works as it should be. Another topic is what do you want for the code to do. Use compound triggers for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work. Because your trigger has `pragma autonomous transaction`, it spawns a new transaction, one in which your changes haven't been committed yet and aren't visible. So when it does `max(id)`, it does not see the uncommitted update that its taking place.

You can get around the mutating table problem with a [compound trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-8A0DA171-BE6A-4798-A1A4-677B88EA16A0).

You could also replace your trigger body with something like (this assumes it only ever has one row in it and it only updated by this trigger):

```
update w_mutating1 set num = greatest( num, :new.id );
```

But there isn't enough information to what problem you're actually trying to solve, so that's the best I can do.